# In node.js, how do I validate UTF8 data in a buffer?

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I need to validate that a buffer contains valid UTF-8 data.

In Python, I can do this by simply trying to decode the bytes and checking for exceptions.
In the example below, I try to decode the 1st byte of encoded '¢'. The exception tells me that I'm missing bytes.

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = '¢'
>>> s_bytes[:1].decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

This approach doesn't work in node.js because the decoding is much more forgiving.

```
> s = '¢'
'¢'
> s_buffer = Buffer(s)
<Buffer c2 a2>
> s_buffer.toString('utf8', 0, 1)
'?'
>
```

I checked the [Buffer API page](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) but I can't find any method for validating the buffer against an encoding.